# Can the asyncpostbacktrigger of an update panel have two control IDs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a button outside an update panel which controls an update panel very well. I also want another button to update this same update panel when the click event is triggered. How can I achieve this?

Comment: See this - http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have multiple triggers registered to a single update panel. Something like the following should work:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" EventName="Click" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```